# How to register events using reflection in C#

Tags: c#, .net

As a disclaimer, I am completely new to C#. That been said, I was looking for a lightweight pub/sub library in C# I can use which would be similar to something like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pubsub-js) in Javascript that I am used to. However all I could find was for .NET version 4 or higher. I have to use .NET 3.5. So I decided to write my own and I call this an EventBus. The goal is to have other classes to freely subscribe / publish events that are pre-defined in the EventBus. However I found out that the "event" in C# is not first class citizen so I couldn't pass that as a parameter to a function. So I decided to pass enum instead to indicate which event is of interest at the moment. My EventBus works fine as intended but as you can see in my code, I run into the problem of keep writing switch cases in all 3 functions whenever I add a new event. Here is my code.

```
public class EventBus {
    public delegate void EventListener(object source, EventArgs args);

    private static event EventListener MapLocationMarkerClicked;

    public static void Subscribe(Event eventToSub, EventListener listener)
    {
        switch(eventToSub)
        {
            case Event.MapLocationMarkerClicked:
                MapLocationMarkerClicked += listener;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void Unsubscribe(Event eventToUnsub, EventListener listener)
    {
        switch (eventToUnsub)
        {
            case Event.MapLocationMarkerClicked:
                MapLocationMarkerClicked -= listener;
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void Publish(Event eventToPub, object source, EventArgs args)
    {
        switch (eventToPub)
        {
            case Event.MapLocationMarkerClicked:
                MapLocationMarkerClicked(source, args);
                break;
        }
    }
}

public enum Event
{
    MapLocationMarkerClicked
}
```

Is there a way to achieve all of the subscribe / unsubscribe / publish actions without switch statements like this? I was wondering how C#'s reflection could help in this situation. Maybe once the enum (or a literal string) is passed to indicate an event, it is used to find the event using reflection and perform the action?

Comment: With a little more context (what is it for?) someone might be able to advice a messaging system or interfaces or ...

Comment: Or look into moderator pattern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need reflection, you can use an [`EventHandlerList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.eventhandlerlist.aspx). However, the `EventHandlerList` does not take an enum, but an `object` as a key. But you can easily overcome this restriction with an intermediate dictionary:

```
static Dictionary<Event, object> eventMap = new Dictionary<Event, object>() { { Event.MapLocationMarkerClicked, new object() } };
static EventHandlerList events = new EventHandlerList();

public static void Subscribe(Event eventToSub, EventListener listener)
{
    events.AddHandler(eventMap[eventToSub], listener);
}

public static void Unsubscribe(Event eventToUnsub, EventListener listener)
{
    events.RemoveHandler(eventMap[eventToSub], listener);
}

public static void Publish(Event eventToPub, object source, EventArgs args)
{
    EventListener listener = (EventListener)events[eventMap[eventToSub]];
    listener?.Invoke(source, args);
}
```

You will probably want to take a look at the [`IObservable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd990377.aspx)/[`IObserver<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783449.aspx) interfaces, which are the .NET publish/subscribe interfaces.

Comment: Oh ok, so this is just relying on your own events - listeners mapping instead of registering listeners to the events with += operator given by C#?

Comment: @jiminssy: The event handler list is intended for objects with a large amount of events with only a few of them being assigned event handlers. The WinForm `Control` makes extensive use of event handler lists.

Comment: It seems like this could be able to handle 1 : N relationship between event : listener. Is that correct? In which case this is exactly what I was looking for! I would then just simply keep adding more events in the eventMap initialization. One question I have is that you are doing simple new Object() into the Dictionary. Can I build hierarchy using inheritance here to introduce relationships between events? (Ex. I want to subscribe to all mouse related events)

Comment: It can do exactly what an event handler does. It is designed exactly for that scenario. So, yes, since you can add multiple handlers to an event, you can do that in `EventHandlerList`, too.

Comment: Could it do hierarchical events? Get all listeners using parent class event and invoke them all.

Comment: You have to do hierarchy yourself. This is for event handlers, not a publish/subscribe framework.

Comment: That's right. I looked at the source code for EventHandlerList and it turns out it retrieves the event handler by comparing objects in the list with == with the given object. This is a reference check. It has no logics to deal with hierarchies. Thanks!